# How do you find the "placeholder" attribute using typescript?

Tags: typescript, each, placeholder

How do you find the html "placeholder" attribute using **typescript** and use that element inside a function?

Comment: I did the same thing in jquery...I would be greatful if you could tell me a way of using the element after finding the attribute

Comment: So are you trying to target all elements that have a placeholder attribute and then do something with those elements, or am I misunderstanding? Also, you mentioned in your comment that you did the same in jQuery. Does that imply that you are not wanting to use jQuery here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is pretty broad. As an example given the html:

```
<input placeholder="tada" id="foo"/>
```

The following works:

```
alert(document.getElementById('foo').getAttribute('placeholder'))
```

## UPDATE

Fix for comment:

```
$('input[type = "text"][placeholder]')
           .each(function () { 
                    console.log(this.getAttribute('placeholder')); // this is the DOM element
           });
```

Comment: You should always use the direct `.attribute` method if you want programmatic access to an attribute in JavaScript. Use `.getAttribute()` and `.setAttribute()` when you wish to deal with the DOM as it is (e.g. literal text only).

Comment: ('input[type = "text"][placeholder]').each(function () {
 console.log($(this).attr('placeholder')); // Error over here
}

Can you tell me a different way to access the element inside this

Comment: What sort of error are you getting? Out of curiosity are you using any sort of TypeScript definition file for jQuery?

Comment: Thanks... exactly what I wanted

Comment: @basarat OP didn't wanted to know how to achieve this aim by using jQuery. He wanted to do it in typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Your **HTML** input element:

```
<input id='randomId' type='text' val='value' placeholder='This text is just a placeholder!'>
```

*Accessing* the *element* in javascript:

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById('randomId');
```

*Checking* for *browser support* of the placeholder attribute in javascript:

```
// I like having such a simple class ...
var Browser = {
  CanAttribute: function (name) {
    return name in document.createElement('input'); 
  }
}

// ... so you can easily check if your browser supports the placeholder attribute.
if (Browser.CanAttribute('placeholder')) {

}
else {

}
```

*Checking* for *existence of attribute* in javascript:

```
if ('placeholder' in inputElement) {
  // You can access inputElement.placeholder
}
else {
  // Accessing inputElement.placeholder will throw an ReferenceError-Exception
}
```

*Retrieving* the placeholder *attribute* via javascript:

```
var placeholderText = inputElement.placeholder;
console.log(placeholderText); // 'This text is just a placeholder!'
```

*Setting* the placeholder *attribute* via javascript:

```
inputElement.placeholder = 'This placeholder text overrides the default text!';
console.log(placeholderText); // 'This placeholder text overrides the default text!'
```

Comment: ('input[type = "text"][placeholder]').each(function () {
 console.log($(this).attr('placeholder')); // Error over here
}

Can you tell me a different way to access the element inside this

Comment: Sure :) Instead of `$(this).attr('placeholder')` you can just write it like this: `this.placeholder`